# list item does not work in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-listview

After running application using android studio ,when i clicked on list item nothing happen, what is wrong on my code?

```
package com.asaad.siag.asaad;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import static java.lang.String.valueOf;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = {"MainActivity", "example 1", "example 2", "example 3", "example 4"
        , "example 5", "example 6"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle v){
    super.onCreate(v);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes [position];
    try {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.asaad.siag.asaad "+ cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

i think it because class.forName

Comment: do  `Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.asaad.siag.asaad."+ cheese);`

Comment: The strings you show in your list contain spaces. You also have a space in the parameter of forName(). Java class names cannot contain spaces. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please check out the page on [how to ask questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help./how-to-ask) in order to get the best help. In particular - you need to specify what happens when you run your code, and what you'd like to happen along with any debugging you've done so far.  You might also try making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: hi yole, i am new in android and i watching thenewboston android tutorials ,according to the part 20 video of thenewboston the above code after running must show a list view and if i click the first item in list view (here is MainActivity) it should open the MainActivity activity. but after running the application i can see the list view but when i clicked on MainActivity item nothings happen. i am using android studio for coding but thenewboston tutorials uses eclipse

Answer (score -1):

you have not a listview here. implement listview in xml file, get it on activity and follow this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
{ 
   //do st
}
});
```

Comment: He has extended ListActivity Class, Have you checked that ?

Comment: sory , so problem is line : Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass); call directly class  and try